# Javascript inheritance and arrays (need examples)

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, inheritance, javascript-objects

I'm trying to extend the array object but I'm getting so confused with the inheritance part of it. Let me demonstrate it with an example:

```js
    function Class1() {
      return Array.apply(null, arguments);
    };

    function Class2() {
      Array.apply(null, arguments);
      return 'ignored?';
    };

    Class1.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
    Class2.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

    var list1 = new Class1('one');

    list1.push(1);

    console.log("list1: ", list1);
     //prints ["one", 1]

    console.log(Array.isArray(list1), list1 instanceof Class1);
     //prints isArray: true, instanceof Class1: false

    var list2 = new Class2('two');
    list2.push(2);

    console.log("list2: ", list2);
     //prints [2] only.. 'two' from constructor is ignored?

    console.log(Array.isArray(list2), list2 instanceof Class2);
     //prints isArray:false,  instanceof Class2: true
     //return value in function Class2 has no effect
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the return value of Class1 makes the list1 an instance of Array but the return value of Class2 is ignored?
2. What is the correct way so that an Object will be an `instanceof Class` test and also pass `Array.isArray(obj)` test?

Thanks for the help. This Javascript inheritance is driving me nuts.

Comment: Why are you mixing constructors with `Object.create`?

Comment: A return value from a constructor that is NOT an object is ignored and the returned object is the one created via `new`, not what was returned.  If the return value IS an object, then that becomes the object that is returned from `new Constructor()`.

Comment: @Mathletics I just want to set the prototypical inheritance chain to Array, so that `push`, etc can work with the derived objects

Comment: Regarding __2__, I don't think you can do that?

Comment: Unless this is an ES6 environment, you cannot inherit from an `Array` and have the magic `.length` property still work correctly.  You can create your own object that contains an array and mimics some of the methods.

Comment: [You cannot subclass `Array`s in ES5](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). Stop trying.

Comment: Actually the reason I'm trying to do this is because of AngularJS.. The problem is AngularJs checks `Array.isArray(obj)` and all `filters` fail is that check is false.. So I need a way to tell Angularjs that my object is indeed an extended array

Comment: @Mathletics: You can via `Object.setPrototypeOf([], MyClass.prototype)`, but it's not recommended for good reason

Comment: @Bergi I tried it but `Array.isArray(list2)` still returns false

Comment: @supersan: Yes, `list2` is not an actual array, it's just an object (even if it inherits from `Array.prototype`). `Array.apply(this)` does not work, and there is no way to make it work.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Bergi. For anyone interested in the angularjs problem i wanted to sort out, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/7mba3daL/ (as you can see the filter fails on `ExtendedObject` because it fails the Array.isArray test and angular ignores it hence)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> 'two' from constructor is ignored?

Note that when the [Array constructor is called with exactly one argument](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-len), it's treated as setting the length. So:

```
var list2 = new Class2('two');
```

calls (effectively):

```
Array('two');
```

which creates a new array. If the single argument is not a number, it's ignored and an empty array is created (see step 7 of the algorithm). This is one reason that it is recommended to use an Array literal or Array initializer rather than the constructor.

Also, *instanceOf* is unreliable. All it does is check if an object has the constructor's prototype somewhere on its `[[Prototype]]` chain.